# How to install npm package globally without internet connection?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, pm2

I need to install pm2 and pm2-windows-service package globally on a computer without an internet connection. I have tried to save each package as a tarball on my own computer (with internet connection) like this:

```
npm pack pm2 
npm pack pm2-windows-startup
```

Then I copy both tarball files 'pm2-4.2.3.tgz' and 'pm2-windows-startup-1.0.3.tgz' to the computer without internet connection and try to install globally as follow:

```
npm i -g pm2-4.2.3.tgz
npm i -g pm2-windows-startup-1.0.3.tgz
```

But I always have the same error ...

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@pm2%2fagent failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Some suggestion to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

According to [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders)

> Global install (with -g): puts stuff in /usr/local or wherever node is installed.

I haven't tried it myself but what I'd try to do is to take the dependency (with all subdependencies) and put it in the directory with your node. Something like `<PATH_TO_NODE>/node_modules`.

Then take the corresponding file from your local `node_modules/.bin` and put it in the `<PATH_TO_NODE>`

If you don't know where your node is installed, you can run this command in the terminal

```sh
npm config get prefix
```

Directories will be [different on UNIX systems](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders).